# How can I put a gridview between two relative layouts?

Tags: android, gridview

I'm building a layout, and I would like to have a centered (At the middle of the screen) gridview between two relative layouts. How can I do that?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        >


    </RelativeLayout>


    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/gvMenu"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1">


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank yout.

Comment: You **could**. But *nested layouts are bad for performances* (if you care about). So, It's better having a big RelativeLayout containing all the stuff inside.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I did the same thing, only using one relative layout

Comment: Which is muuuuuuuuch better.

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you a GridLayout between 2 RelativeLayouts, the size of the layouts will adjust depending on what you put inside them but the GridView will always be between them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/first_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f23f23">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/gvMenu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/second_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gvMenu"
    android:background="#7e92d2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```